# C++/CLI msvc++2010 class problem

Tags: windows, visual-c++, c++-cli

I want to call the member function of a class created in my main function, but I get some error, that I can't call a non-static member function. How to call the public member function "msg" of the "Form1"?

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());

    int test = 0;
    if (test>0) {
        Form1::msg("1");
    } else {
        Form1::msg("2");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot make this code work.  Don't try this without reading a book about Winforms programming first.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance handle of `Form1`. Obviously you shall store the lvalue of `gcnew Form1()` as the object to call `msg` on.

Comment: Try `Form1^ p = gcnew Form1();` to create a managed handle. Pass `p` to `Run()`. Then use `p->msg("1")` and `p->msg("2")`. But Hans is right: this code looks strange. Read a book about WinForms.